# How to load gradle properties from central storage

Tags: gradle

I have multiple projects that are build with gradle. All projects are basically using the same build logic and many common properties, only certain variables are different between projects.

I'd like to centralize all common parts and "include" that in every gradle project, so I don't have to touch every gradle project when some commonly used properties change. I'd also like to have the ability to override properties for special cases.

What's the gradle way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> What's the gradle way to do this?

#### Simple answer: [Initialization scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)

Properties are the best way to set user-/system-specific (using the `gradle.properties` file in the Gradle user home directory) or project-specific (using the `gradle.properties` file in the project directory) parameters. If you want to setup a consistent environment across development systems (local machines, CI, ...) and even multiple users (different credentials), you can develop one or more initialization scripts.

You can place them at your Gradle user home directory (this way they will be used by all Gradle installations) or at your Gradle install directory (for one specific installed Gradle version).

Project and system properties can be set from an initialization script via a [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) object:

```
startParameter.with {
    projectProperties['key'] = 'value'
    systemPropertiesArgs['key'] = 'value'
}
```

Both `projectProperties` and `systemPropertiesArgs` are simple maps.

Comment: I guess there are 2 problems with this solution. I somehow need to deploy the init script to every machine that uses gradle and I can't choose whether to run the initscript or not on a per project basis. I'd rather like to somehow include these things from a remote resource like a git or nexus repository

Comment: If you just want to exclude parts of your `build.gradle` file to use them in multiple projects, you can simply use the `apply from:` command with an url. Host your scripts on a web server (the raw view at GitHub or Bitbucket can be used) and use the url as argument.

Comment: That would be a perfect solution, but how can I manage the login to bitbucket?

Comment: Currently, I did not find any other solution than making the script repository public.